# How to add legends on gauge chart using plotly.graph_object

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts, plotly, data-visualization

I have created a gauge chart but I want to mention the meaning of labels, like 0 = low and 5 = high. that means I will need two labels (low on the left and high on the right).

Here is how my graph look like:
[image]

code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    value = 4.3,
    mode = "gauge+number+delta",
    title = {'text': "General satisfaction"},
    delta = {'reference': 2.5},
    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 5], 'tickwidth': 1,'tickcolor': "black"},
        'bar': {'color': "MidnightBlue"},
             'steps' : [
                 {'range': [0, 1], 'color': "DarkTurquoise"},
                 {'range': [1, 2], 'color': "MediumTurquoise"},
                 {'range': [2, 3], 'color': "Turquoise"},
                 {'range': [3, 4], 'color': "PaleTurquoise"},
                 {'range': [4, 5], 'color': "lightcyan"}],
             'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "brown", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 4.8}}))


fig.show()
```

Is there any parameter that can help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [graph objects indicator](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.indicator.html) **tickmode**, **tickvals** and **ticktext**
- demonstrated below

```
fig.update_traces(
    gauge={
        "axis": {
            "tickmode": "array",
            "tickvals": list(range(6)),
            "ticktext": ["0 - low" if i == 0 else "5 - high" if i==5 else i for i in range(6)],
        }
    }
)
```

[image]